# trimming a string using C++20 ranges

Tags: c++, strings, c++20

I have a function which is supposed to trim a string by removing trailing whitespace, then exactly one instance of a fixed string, if it exists, and then any remaining trailing whitespace.  It works as intended but I'd like to do this neatly just by using views.  Is there a clever and efficient way to do that?  Also, I'm currently limited to C++20, but if there's a nice way to do this with future standards (I already know I'd like to use `std::ranges::to` from C++23), that would be welcome as well.

The `rtrim` function is below with a test function in main to exercise it.  When everything is working as expected, the program prints nothing.

````cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string& rtrim(std::string& str, const std::string_view pattern) {
    auto view = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
        | std::views::reverse
        ;
    str = {view.begin(), view.end()};
    if (str.ends_with(pattern)) {
        str.erase(str.size() - pattern.size(), pattern.size());
    }
    auto view2 = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
        | std::views::reverse
        ;
    return str = {view2.begin(), view2.end()};
}

int main() {
    struct {
        std::string input;
        std::string pattern;
        std::string expected;
    } tests[] = {
        { "xox foo xox", "xox", "xox foo" },
        { "xox foo xox  ", "xox", "xox foo" },
        { "xox foo xoxox  ", "xox", "xox foo xo" },
        { "xox fooxox", "xox", "xox foo" },
        { "xox fooxxxx", "xxx", "xox foox" },
        { "xox fooxxxxx", "xxx", "xox fooxx" },
        { "xox fooxxxxxx", "xxx", "xox fooxxx" },
    };
    for (auto& test : tests) {
        auto result = rtrim(test.input, test.pattern);
        if (result != test.expected) {
            std::cerr << "Expected " << std::quoted(test.expected)
                << " but got " << std::quoted(result)
                << " with input " << std::quoted(test.input)
                << " and pattern " << std::quoted(test.pattern)
                << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Based on the reviews, I did some benchmarks: https://quick-bench.com/q/WUsVo93Ki4eHp4CdMfZbwRnvAjM
The version with custom ranges appears to be fastest.  The version with the space trim function broken out was slowest. A regex version was also tested, but as expected, it's really slow and commented out.

Comment: The benchmarking was inspired by this: https://www.cppstories.com/2022/ranges-perf/ and borrowed some code from there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## The dream of ranges

C++20 is really incomplete in a lot of ways. There were *so many* features added, there was a lot of push just to get the basics in, and add the polish later. Every major feature suffered because of it, including ranges. A lot of the things you *should* do for a problem like this are just not possible until C++23. C++23 really *completes* C++20; in many ways, C++20 is just not “finished” without C++23’s additions. (This happened before, by the way. C++14 was really a “bugfix” for C++11. The standardization for C++11 had gone on for *so long*—it was originally optimistically called C++0x, assuming it would be done before 2010—that they just wanted to get it out there, and then add the polish later.)

What you *should* do is make a custom range adaptor that drops all of the trailing elements for which a predicate is satisfied; a `drop_last_while` adaptor. With that and a `drop_suffix` range adaptor you could do this:

```
auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string&
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    str.resize(
        std::ranges::size(
            str
                | drop_last_while(is_space)
                | drop_suffix(pattern)
                | drop_last_while(is_space)
        )
    );

    // Or, the same, spread out:
    //
    // Transform the string to the final form (as a view):
    //  auto view = str
    //      | drop_last_while(is_space)
    //      | drop_suffix(pattern)
    //      | drop_last_while(is_space);
    //
    // Get the size of the final form:
    // auto const view_size = std::ranges::size(view);
    //
    // Resize the string to that size (works because we're only trimming
    // from the end):
    // str.resize(view_size);

    return str;
}
```

But… you can’t actually make a custom range adaptor in C++20, because they forgot that key little feature. Starting in C++23, you have what you need: [`std::ranges::range_adaptor_closure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range_adaptor_closure).

So, to put it bluntly, you simply can’t do this as “nicely” as you might hope in C++20. You can get *partway* there, but not all the way.

(Incidentally, I don’t see why you’d want to use `ranges::to` in a case like this. That just doesn’t make any sense. `ranges::to` creates a new object from a range… but you already have the object you want: `str`. You are modifying that object, so why would you want to create a new one?)

You can’t create range adaptors in C++20, but you *can* create views. That’s a little clunkier, but it’ll have to do.

So, what you’d want to do is create a `drop_last_while_view`. For bidirectional views or better, that’s pretty trivial:

```
template <std::ranges::view V, typename Pred>
    requires
        std::ranges::forward_range<V>
        and std::is_object_v<Pred>
        and std::indirect_unary_predicate<Pred const, std::ranges::iterator_t<V>>
class drop_last_while_view
    : public std::ranges::view_interface<drop_last_while_view<V, Pred>>
{
public:
    constexpr drop_last_while_view()
        requires std::default_initializable<V>
            and std::default_initializable<Pred>
        : _begin{std::ranges::begin(V{})}
        , _end{std::ranges::end(V{})}
    {}

    constexpr drop_last_while_view(V base, Pred pred)
        requires std::ranges::bidirectional_range<V>
        : _begin{std::ranges::begin(base)}
        , _end{std::ranges::end(base)}
    {
        while ((_end != _begin) and std::invoke(pred, *std::ranges::prev(_end)))
            --_end;
    }

    // Forward iterator version left as an exercise for the reader!
    //constexpr drop_last_while_view(V base, Pred pred) { ??? }

    constexpr auto begin() const { return _begin; }

    constexpr auto end() const { return _end; }

private:
    std::ranges::iterator_t<V> _begin;
    std::ranges::iterator_t<V> _end;
};

template <typename R, typename Pred>
drop_last_while_view(R&&, Pred) -> drop_last_while_view<std::views::all_t<R>, Pred>;
```

Same idea for `drop_suffix_view`. Then your function is:

```
auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string&
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    auto const v1 = drop_last_while_view{str, is_space};
    auto const v2 = drop_suffix_view{v1, pattern};
    auto const v3 = drop_last_while_view{v2, is_space};

    str.resize(std::ranges::size(v3));

    return str;
}
```

If you make a `constexpr` `is_space`, then you can make the whole thing `constexpr`.

Now, if you’re asking how to write this using only *existing* views and range adaptors… well, then you’ve more or less got the gist of it. There will necessarily be a lot of reversing and un-reversing, because none of the standard views or range adaptors work on the *end* of a range. You kinda “cheat” in the middle by not using a view to remove the suffix… I mean, if you’re going to do that, then you could do the whole operation without ranges or views and just operate on the string directly. So here’s how I’d do it in all C++20 ranges/views, no cheating:

```
auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string&
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); };

    auto view = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while(is_space)
        | std::views::reverse
    ;

    str.resize(std::ranges::size(view));

    auto const pattern_size = std::ranges::size(pattern);

    if (std::ranges::equal(str | std::views::reverse | std::views::take(pattern_size), pattern | std::views::reverse))
    {
        auto view = str
            | std::views::reverse
            | std::views::drop(pattern_size)
            | std::views::drop_while(is_space)
            | std::views::reverse
        ;

        str.resize(std::ranges::size(view));
    }

    return str;
}
```

But, IMO, this is silly. Compare that to what you’d get if you made the necessary views, like I showed above. And compare it to what you could if you could write your own range adaptors:

```
// With only custom views (C++20):
auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string&
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    auto const v1 = drop_last_while_view{str, is_space};
    auto const v2 = drop_suffix_view{v1, pattern};
    auto const v3 = drop_last_while_view{v2, is_space};

    str.resize(std::ranges::size(v3));

    return str;
}


// With custom range adaptors (C++23):
auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string&
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    auto view = str
        | drop_last_while(is_space)
        | drop_suffix(pattern)
        | drop_last_while(is_space)
    ;

    str.resize(std::ranges::size(view));

    return str;
}
```

*That* is what range-based code is supposed to look like. You just can’t do that with standard views or range adaptors in C++20, and without C++23 you can’t even get all the way to the last example at all.

One more thing to note: because you are modifying the string you were passed, you aren’t really getting into the full “vibe” of ranges. To really grok ranges, you have to think in terms of returning *views*—either sub-views or modified views or both—not modifying ranges directly.

So if I were *really* doing this fully-range-flavoured, I would basically make a function that looks more like this:

```
auto rtrim(std::string_view str, std::string_view pattern)
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    auto view = str
        | drop_last_while(is_space)
        | drop_suffix(pattern)
        | drop_last_while(is_space)
    ;

    return std::string_view{view};
}
```

And then I would rework that as a range adaptor, so I could write:

```
auto result = test.input | rtrim(test.pattern);
```

## Ranges/views are not really the best way to write library code

However, that’s all nice and sexy, and if I were writing that operation quick-and-dirty, that would be fine. But if I were implementing this operation as a *library* function… it could be better.

This is often true for range-based code. It’s great at the application level, or for one-time problem solving. It’s not always great for stuff that needs to be *tight*, like high-performance or library code.

Let’s look again at the “ideal” code:

```
auto rtrim(std::string_view str, std::string_view pattern)
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    auto view = str
        | drop_last_while(is_space)
        | drop_suffix(pattern)
        | drop_last_while(is_space)
    ;

    return std::string_view{view};
}
```

So, first we do the `drop_last_while` to remove trailing whitespace, if any. That’s fine; it’s about as ideal as we can get.

Then we drop the suffix, if any. Again, this is as ideal as it’s going to get.

But *then* we do the `drop_last_while` to remove trailing whitespace again, and here’s the rub: if we didn’t drop the suffix, we don’t need to do this.

So, for the best performance, we’d want something more like:

```
auto rtrim(std::string_view str, std::string_view pattern)
{
    auto const is_space = [](auto c) { return std::isspace(c); }

    auto view = std::string_view{str | drop_last_while(is_space)};

    if (view.ends_with(pattern))
    {
        view = std::string_view{
            view
                | drop_last(std::ranges::size(pattern))
                | drop_last_while(is_space)
        };
    }

    return view;
}
```

But even this isn’t *perfect*, because there is still unnecessary/duplicated work being done. To do the `ends_with` check we have to read the pattern and figure out its size… but then we need to do that again for the `drop_last` (which isn’t a standard view, just in case that isn’t clear).

To *really* make this routine as efficient as it possibly can be, you pretty much have to toss out ranges, and work with iterators. You get the end iterator, and keep moving it backwards for each phase of the transformation. So long as you keep track of that iterator, you won’t need to do any unnecessary work.

So, what I’m saying is: ranges-based code is fine and good for one-and-done stuff, high-level-logic, and application code. But when you really need the highest performance, the lowest memory usage… just the maximum of efficiency in general… ranges will often not be your friend. It’s the classic trade-off: do you want clear, high-level code… or do you want high-performance code. Ranges do a spectacular job of letting you eat your cake and have it, too… but not a *perfect* job.

If your `rtrim()` function is not meant to be library code, intended to be the *best* implementation to give users the highest performance, then ranges are fine. Otherwise… you might have to ditch the sexy ranges and get low-level dirty.

## The lurking bug

Even with the ideal C++23 ranges code, there is still one dangerous thing to watch out for. And this is something you *almost* do in your own code. More on that in the review, though.

Consider this:

```
auto str = std::string{"whatever"};
str = str | rtrim("pattern");
```

Now, the right-hand side of the assignment creates a view into the character data of `str`. Which you then assign to `str`.

In other words, you are assigning the character data of a string—or some part of its character data—to itself. In essence: `str.assign(str.begin(), str.end())`, or `std.assign(str.begin() + n, str.end() - m)` assuming `n + m <= str.size()`.

That will result in implementation-defined behaviour, because you can’t know what order the characters of the string will be assigned over itself. In fact, there are a lot of things the string could *technically* do that would break your assumptions. For example, the string may allocate a new buffer, then delete the old buffer, *then* copy the characters but oh no now it’s copying from freed memory.

Granted, I know that at least `libstdc++` and `libc++` behave as you’d expect when copying a string’s data over itself (at least I think I know that… it’s been many versions since I check). And I’ve seen some debate among experts about whether it is *supposed* to work. All I can say for certain is this: `std::string` does not explicitly *guarantee* this will work. So a conforming implementation does not have to make it work.

As a general rule, I would say that if you modify a container while holding a view of it, you are almost always doing something wrong.

That is why, in my rewrites of your code (see the “no cheating” version above in particular), I am very careful not to assign to the string. I use `resize()` instead. And I abandon/remake any views after I’ve modified the string.

You don’t actually trigger this bug in your code… but only because you do something silly. I’ll get to that in the review.

## Code review

```
std::string& rtrim(std::string& str, const std::string_view pattern)
```

So, your function modifies the string… *and* returns a reference to it. I’m not a fan of that kind of interface. If a function takes reference parameters and modifies them, it should either return a *different* “thing” (like an error code or something), or `void`. It should not return the reference it’s modifying. At the very least, this creates confusion: without consulting the documentation, a user won’t know if they are supposed to assign the return value or not, and they might accidentally modify a string they didn’t intend to because they thought only the return value is modified.

A better idea would be to embrace modern design principles and *never* modify arguments. In other words:

```
auto rtrim(std::string str, const std::string_view pattern) -> std::string
```

This can be just as efficient as passing references around, if you use moves. Instead of:

```
auto str = "some string with a suffix"s;
auto&& trimmed = rtrim(str, "suffix");

// Now, without knowing the function, riddle me this:
//  1.  Is str unchanged?
//  2.  Is trimmed a reference to str?
//
// How can I know that str will not be corrupted if I change trimmed?
// How can I know that trimmed will not be corrupted if I change str?
```

you do:

```
auto str = "some string with a suffix"s;
auto&& trimmed = rtrim(std::move(str), "suffix");

// Just the addition of the move() sends a clear signal: trimmed cannot be
// a reference to str (or at least, it would be idiotic if it were, because
// str was passed as an rvalue).
//
// So I can safely do anything I want with str, and trimmed will be
// unaffected. And vice versa.
```

or:

```
auto const str = "some string with a suffix"s;
auto&& trimmed = rtrim(str, "suffix");

// The const sends a different signal. Even if trimmed is a reference to str,
// there is no fear of causing corruption by inadvertently modifying str
// via trimmed. And since str is const, there is no fear of trimmed being
// modified either.
//
// So again, without even looking at the docs, I know that neither str nor
// trimmed are in danger of being corrupted by spooky action at a distance.
```

Of course, you *could* write:

```
auto str = "some string with a suffix"s;
auto&& trimmed = rtrim(str, "suffix");
```

and end up with the original uncertainty. But that would be your fault. If you want the uncertainty to go away, you just need to write better code, either by making `str` `const` (or using `std::as_const()`), or moving it. But you *can’t* write that better code with the original interface. That’s why it’s a bad interface.

For maximum performance, you might want to write some overloads:

```
auto rtrim(std::string&& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string
{
    // Basically your function now, except with return std::move(str);
}

auto rtrim(std::string const& str, std::string_view pattern) -> std::string
{
    return rtrim(std::string{str}, pattern);
}
```

You may also want to have a *second* function that works with views:

```
auto rtrim_view(std::string_view, std::string_view) -> std::string_view;
```

You could write the non-view function in terms of the view function. Just run the view function, get the size of the view, and use the `resize()` trick (in the rvalue case; in the lvalue case, you can just construct a new string from the view).

```
    str = {view.begin(), view.end()};
```

Do you realize what you’re doing here is creating an entire second string, copying part of first string into it, then copying that back into the original string?

There is no reason to create an entire second temporary string when you’re literally just copying some part the original string’s contents back into it. All you need to do is tell either the original what part(s) to keep, or what part(s) to drop.

Now, I mentioned the lurking bug above, and how you *almost* trigger it, but not quite. This is because you copy the character data from `str` to a *new* string… then copy that *new* string’s (identical) character data *back* to `str`. Which is silly. But, by blind luck it avoids the problem of copying `str`’s own data *directly* into itself.

A naïve solution would be to use a string view:

```
    str = std::string_view{view.begin(), view.end()};
```

But that would trigger the bug. Without that extra string as an intermediary, you are copying a string’s data back into itself.

There is no need to copy anything at all. The data you want is already in `str`. You just need to get rid of all the *other* crud. You know *where* the data you want is in `str`, too. Because you only trimmed from the end, the data you want is `[str.begin(), str.begin() + ???)`, where `???` is the size of the view. You don’t need the *contents* of the view; they’re already in `str`. You just need to know its *size*.

Thus:

```
    str.resize(view.size());
```

Which transforms `str`’s contents to `[str.begin(), str.begin() + view.size())`… which is what you want. No need for extra strings. No dangerous lurking bugs. Simple. Fast.

```
    if (str.ends_with(pattern)) {
        str.erase(str.size() - pattern.size(), pattern.size());
    }
    auto view2 = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
        | std::views::reverse
        ;
```

If `str` does *not* end with `pattern`, there is no need to do the second run of the whitespace trimming. So why not:

```
auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view const pattern) -> std::string&
{
    auto view = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
        | std::views::reverse
        ;
    str = {view.begin(), view.end()}; // should use resize()

    if (str.ends_with(pattern))
    {
        str.erase(str.size() - pattern.size(), pattern.size());

        auto view2 = str
            | std::views::reverse
            | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
            | std::views::reverse
            ;
        str = {view2.begin(), view2.end()}; // should use resize()
    }

    return str;
}
```

You should have noticed that you’re doing the whitespace right trim twice. That’s a function!

```
auto rtrim(std::string& str) -> std::string&
{
    auto view = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
        | std::views::reverse
        ;

    str = {view.begin(), view.end()}; // should use resize()

    return str;
}

auto rtrim(std::string& str, std::string_view const pattern) -> std::string&
{
    rtrim(str);

    if (str.ends_with(pattern))
    {
        str.erase(str.size() - pattern.size(), pattern.size());
        rtrim(str);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Finally:

```
    return str = {view2.begin(), view2.end()};
```

There is no benefit to cramming operations together like this. There are two distinct logical operations here: an assignment to `str`, and a `return` statement. They should be on two distinct lines.

That’s all! Have a good one!

Comment: I'm confused about the `std::move()` version of `rtrim()`. The comment on this code: `auto str = "some string with a suffix"s; auto&& trimmed = rtrim(std::move(str), "suffix");` says that `// this function does NOT modify str`. Doesn't the call to `std::move()` modify `str`? After the call to `rtrim()`, the string `str` should be empty or in some other unknown but valid state.

Comment: As an aside, you really don't want the character-classification-functions meet a `char` widened to `int`. Go the proper way over `unsigned char`.

Comment: Regarding the lurking bug, it's even harder to hit than you thought: While contrary to your thought re-allocation is only possible when shrinking, which doesn't happen here, if source and destination overlap, one gets UB.

Comment: Also, in contradiction to the assertion that "Ranges/views are not really the best way to write library code" my testing shows that using custom views is the fastest code of the six different version I wrote and tested.

Comment: @MarkH Yeah, I went back and forth between whether to show the `const` or move thing first, and in that comment you’re seeing the confusion from that. I mean, it’s technically true: the function does *not* modify `str` (`str` is gone before the function starts), and the move *does* signal that fact. But what I meant to get at was that this spelling signals that modifying `str` does not affect `trimmed`, because `trimmed` can’t be a (lvalue) reference to `str`. I’ll reword the comment so it makes more sense.

Comment: @Deduplicator Definitely agree about the C version of `std::isspace()`, and would go farther to say: never use it at all. Either use the C++ version to get proper locale support if that’s what you want, or roll your own copy of the C version: `inline constexpr auto isspace(char c) noexcept { return c == ' ' or c == '\n' or c == '\r' or c == '\f' or c == '\v'; }`. There is no good reason to use the C version, and several reasons why it’s bad. Same goes for the rest of the `<cctype>` functions, both the `is*()` ones and the `to*()` ones.

Answer (score 5):

## helper function

```
    auto view2 = str
        | std::views::reverse
        | std::views::drop_while([](char x){ return std::isspace(x); })
        | std::views::reverse
        ;
```

That's the second time we've seen that same snippet.
If you code up a small private helper function,
then you can

1. shrink the `rtrim` function by expressing what it does at a higher level, and
2. separately unit test the helper.

Also, it seems like it would be generally useful on its own,
and so worth exposing as part of your Public API.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite inefficient. It constructs a new `std::string` several times. Also, it modifies the input string. Why not create a function that only operates on `std::string_view`s?

```
std::string_view rtrim(std::string_view str, const std::string_view pattern);
```

Or if you really mean to modify the string in-place, make this clear by not returning a reference to the input:

```
void rtrim(std::string& str, const std::string_view pattern);
```